# How to handle large datatables c# and update database

Tags: c#, datatable, datagrid, ado.net

Good day.

I am asking for a bit of advise on what other experience has been and pitfalls ect. I am a SQL developer but needing to write a front end using c#.

I am returning a query from a MSSQL database via a stored procedure and putting it into a Datatable. There are about 140k rows in the result set. I am using standard calls with a datareader to return the resultset. No binding.

What I would like to do is return parts of the datatable to datagrid on a form and allow a user to manipulate the data in the grid and save back to the datatable then collect the next part of the datatable and manipulate that. I don't want to to pull things into a datatable in segments as I need to update calculations on the entire datatable when a change is made.

And then finally save the changes back to the database, when done.

If anyone can point me to a the best and most efficient way it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance
Scott

Comment: Most of the databound controls in .NET support paging - I'd google for some examples of how to implement paging for the control you plan on using.

Comment: Thanks Tim it is not so much paging, but more of a filtered sub set of the data by say category client ect. Im currently leaning at the moment creating the datatable locally in a xml and maybe working off that. Was hoping not to have to use linq though.

Comment: Curious - why do *not* want to use LINQ?

Comment: It looks like I am going to have to learn it, it is just I am more comfortable using T-Sql as 90% of the work I do is back end related but the more I am digging linq looks like it is going to be a better route to follow.

Comment: It takes a bit to learn it, but once you understand the syntax the underlying principles should be easy to grasp, since you're coming from a SQL background.  I use it extensively now - even when I'm not dealing with a database per se.  BTW, the reason for the different syntax (SQL) is, as I understand it, to enable intellisense to work in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have already order a book online so I hope in a few days I should be up and running with Linq.